# Can I use HCatInputFormat with MultipleInputs in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

I'm attempting to do a join between two datasets, one is stored in a Hive table, the other one is not. I see according to what people do this is not very normal, as in, they either define everything as a Hive table or they don't.

Now there's the MultipleInputs class, but the addInputPath method takes Configuration, **Path**, InputFormat, Mapper

I could use the input format there and try the to put the table name disguised as a Path but that sounds like a wild guess at best.

There's a patch for newer version of Hive (I'm on CDH4 so that means hive 0.10 and hcat 0.5 sadly). I found this patch which is not quite straight forward to translate into my current version and also seems to only work with multiple tables and not a mix of them.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4997

Is this possible or have you any recommendations?

The only thing I can think of is reading the raw data without using the table, but that implies logic over hive specific formats I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here apparently is either upgrade to 0.14.0 (or patch the old version) or not use HCatalog but read the metastore directly and manually add each partition subdirectory to MultipleInputs.

Personally since I can't upgrade easily and the subpartitioning is too much work, I just focused on optimising the jobs in other ways and be contempt with running a sequence of jobs for now.

Comment: How do you do it in 0.14.0?  It looks like the patch was never committed.

Comment: :( when I posted this it was supposedly there, maybe they realised they left it out afterwards, but it seems like you are correct, I've been out of big data for a while, is Hive dieing perhaps? not being maintained?

Comment: I think spark is where it's at now.

Answer (score 1):

**HCatMultipleInputs** can be used for reading multiple hive tables.

Here is a patch (for 0.13) that we can look at installing for multiple table support. It has HCatMultipleInputs to support multiple hive tables.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/HIVE-4997

```
 
Example useage:
HCatMultipleInputs.addInput(job,Table1, db1, properites1, Mapper1.class);
```

You can use the working code in the below link:
https://github.com/abhirj87/training/tree/master/multipleinputs

Comment: I posted that same link in the question and exactly why I don't want that as a solution, I fail to see how this addresses my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to implement the patch alone in a seperate mapreduce program. It seems that the Patch is still not committed, but i want to use the solution in my job.